# Android: Can I make POST request when app is closed?

Tags: android, database

excuse my English, I need to know how to make a POST to an external data base when the app is closed, I really do not know how or tools used or even if possible, I thank in advance the advice and answers.

Comment: Use Service to make POST requests in background, i.e. when app is not visible.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people have already commented, you will want to make the request using an HTTP library such as OkHttp in a background `Service`. The `Service` lifecycle is independent of the `Activity`s, but is still part of the `Application`, therefore care needs to be taken to make sure the `Service` is defined correctly for your needs (For example, whether you need to `Service` to be restarted if it's killed by the system `START_STICKY`). See the links below for more details:

http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the exact event on exit callback function in the android activity. but you can definitely call restful service from android application.

I have used spring for android to call restful services. check out the below link 
[Spring for android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do, You can use `BroadcastReceiver` to start a service in background. BroadcastReceiver can be triggered by some events. You can read about it more on [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).